# Mongo Query, Find whether a string is present in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
Person = { name: string}
const names = {John, Mark, Fady}
```

how to make a find query to get all the persons that their names are in the array?
i could make a loop over the array and make a find query for every element but this will not be efficient since it will make N find queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db.collection.find( { name: { $in: ['John', 'Mark', 'Fady' ] } } )